# How to shrink logo size when scrolling down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

if you go to http://www.baycrest.org/b2btest/index2.html 
When scrolling down, I want the logo to shrink and fit in to the white bar. Is this done using Javascript? Or just pure CSS? If you know of any templates, that would help greatly too. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use css transitions and javascript/jquery to achive the effect.On scroll event add a  new class to the header and add styles for the logo to shrink.A demo snippet for example.

```js
$(document).on("scroll", function(){
  if
      ($(document).scrollTop() > 50){
        $("header").addClass("shrink");
    }
  else
  {
   $("header").removeClass("shrink");
  }
 });
```

```css
*{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
.header{
  padding:20px;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed; 
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out ;
  transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out ;
  z-index:999;
  background:#FFF;
  width:100%;
  border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
}
.header img{
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out ;
     transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out ;
     width:75px;
     height:75px;
}
 
.shrink{
  padding:10px; 
}

.shrink img{
   width:50px;
    height:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="header">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" title="logo">
</header>
  
<div class="container">
  <p><strong>Scroll down</strong></p>
  <p>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p> 
    <p>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p> 
    <p>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p> 
    <p>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p> 
    <p>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p> 
    <p>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p> 
</div>
```

Comment: Wow thanks so much XYZ. It worked, I just have one more question, what if I wanted the logo to shrink within the white bar when someone looks at it on their smart phone?

Comment: @Jeff use css media queries.and set the size of the log smaller in the width of mobile screen.so when the user opens it will be smaller in header. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: Wow, just wow this is unbelievable. I used the media queries and it worked. I thought it was some javascript function but with your help you really made my day and saved me. Thank you so much XYZ...amazing

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery's on-scroll event to get the location of the scroll from top. Based on that you can apply different CSS classes to the logo and change its size dynamically.

```
$(window).on('scroll',function(event){
  console.log(event);
});
```

Read more [here](https://api.jquery.com/on/).

Another cool library for nicely handling the page header on scroll events is [Headroom.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/headroom.js/). You should check it out.